# File upload validation using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to upload images only. My code will detect whether it is an image or not but I want to disable the button until the file selection is correct, i.e. an image. Only then should the button be enabled.

Whether it uses AngularJs, javascipt or jQuery is not important.

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateFileUpload() {
        var fuData = document.getElementById('fileChooser');
        var FileUploadPath = fuData.value;

        //To check if user upload any file
        if (FileUploadPath == '') {
            alert("Please upload an image");

        } else {
            var Extension = FileUploadPath.substring(
                FileUploadPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();

            //The file uploaded is an image

            if (Extension == "gif" || Extension == "png" || Extension == "bmp"
                || Extension == "jpeg" || Extension == "jpg") {

                // To Display
                if (fuData.files && fuData.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    }

                    reader.readAsDataURL(fuData.files[0]);
                }

            }

            //The file upload is NOT an image
            else {
                alert("Photo only allows file types of GIF, PNG, JPG, JPEG and BMP. ");

            }
        }
    }
```

```
<input type="file" name="dataFile" id="fileChooser" onchange="returnValidateFileUpload()" /><img src="images/noimg.jpg" id="blah"></br><input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"  />
```

Comment: you can to use some file upload library. I like that: http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-file-upload

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038235/is-it-possible-to-load-a-specific-file-type-using-javascript from 2 minutes ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-accept) attribute set to `"image/*"`

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

Comment: accept="image/*" but it is not validated correctly because if user select another file then what the solution

Comment: @chaitanya _"accept="image/*" but it is not validated correctly because if user select another file then what the solution"_ ? What do you mean by "but it is not validated correctly" ? User should only be able to select files from user filesystem where MIME type begins with `"image/"`

Comment: @chaitanya Try removing `"return"` at `onchange="returnValidateFileUpload()"` ; the function name appears to be is `ValidateFileUpload()` not `returnValidateFileUpload()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

Comment: How is your posted solution different from http://stackoverflow.com/a/36038209/ ?

Comment: i think we almost posted at the same time approx(1min) difference.