# Is it possible to load a specific file type using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, filereader

I have a function that is loading a user selected file using the Javascript File API, but I want to limit the type of file that can be loaded.  Is this possible and how do I go about doing it?  So for example, I only want the user to be able to load a DAT file.  Here's my function loading the file.

```
function readFile(file){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var holder;
    var holderArray = [];
    var fileArray = [];
    reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
    reader.onload = function(){
        file = reader.result;
        file = file.split(/\s+/g);
        formatFile(holderArray, 3, holder, file, fileArray);
        for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            formatFile(holderArray, 1, holder, file, fileArray);
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            formatFile(holderArray, 2, holder, file, fileArray);
        }
        var meh = file.length / fileArray.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < meh; i++){
            formatFile(holderArray, 5, holder, file, fileArray);
        }
        fileArray.pop();

        plume = new Plume(fileArray[0], fileArray[4], fileArray[3]);
        $("#eventDate").val(plume.dateTime);
        $("#eventLat").val(plume.startLat);
        $("#eventLon").val(plume.startLong);
        $("#eventDictionary").val(plume.dict);
        $("#eventSymbol").val(plume.symbol);

        fileArray = fileArray.splice(5);
        plume.graphic = fileArray;
    }
}

$("#load").on("click", function(){
    $("#eventNameInput").val("");
    var selectedFile = $("#selectedFile");
    selectedFile = selectedFile[0].files[0];
    if(selectedFile){
        readFile(selectedFile);
        $("#fileDetails").show();
    }
})
```

Comment: No matter what, do not trust the client-side file validation.  Verify the file's type either by MIME type or other authentication on the server as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the ability to handle anything on the server side .  Would I be able to verify the MIME type on the client side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. You can declare MIME type in "accept" attribute For example this input will upload images :

```
<input type="file" name="img" accept="image/*">
```

for .dat you can do this (.dat is unknown MIME type):

```
<input type="file" name="img" accept=".dat">
```

Comment: @Robert, I think you should use `accept=".dat"`. Since there is no standard mime type for `.dat` files.